# Auto-generate Javadoc comments in intelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, intellij-14

Is it possible to auto-generate Javadoc comments for each method in one class in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes.

Under `Tools` you have `Generate JavaDoc`. Read about it in the [official site](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-javadoc-reference-for-a-project.html).

In addition you may ([Intellij 15](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-code.html#link12)):

> Position caret above a method name, type /** and press Enter to let IntelliJ IDEA automatically generate JavaDoc stubs for this method

**Edit:** You can use the action `Fix doc comment`. It doesn't have a default shortcut, but you can assign the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> shortcut to it in the Keymap, because this shortcut isn't used for anything else.

Comment: didn't work for me. Is there any shortcut such as in eclipse shift+alt+j

Comment: @Madan what do you mean by *didn't work*? Did you read https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generate-javadoc-dialog.html ? Also see my **Edit**

Comment: I mean Positioning caret above a method name and typing /** didn't worked . I made assigned shortcut and worked for me thanks... :-)

Comment: did you press Enter

Comment: I think the question is not how to generate JavaDoc from existing source, rather how to add JavaDoc comments to source files. If my understanding is correct, then please refer to this question

Comment: How to generate bulk comments for entire module. Keep in mind that I am not asking about Java Doc. I am asking about method/class doc comments.

Comment: For `Java`, install `JavaDoc` plugin and for `Kotlin`, install `KDoc` plugin under `File -> Settings -> Plugins -> type the plugin name in search bar` for this solution to work correctly.

Answer (score 12):

A QuickShortCut is

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> 
From the dropdown List "**Fix doc comment**"

Answer (score 8):

You can use [JavaDoc plugin](http://setial.github.io/intellij-javadocs/) for generation JavaDoc comments in batch mode.  It is the simpliest way for do it.